# How to iterate all files inside folder and run curl command to install AEM packages

Tags: shell, unix, curl, aem, windows-shell

I am trying to create a shell script which to iterate  all the zip files and install those in AEM package manager using curl command.
The below single curl command is working, It is properly installing the package in respective AEM instance.

```
curl -u admin:admin -F file=@"content-ope.zip" -F name="content-ope.zip" -F force=true -F install=true http://localhost:4502/crx/packmgr/service.jsp
```

But we have to install many zip files so we are planning to keep all of them in one folder, iterate all the zip files and install using curl command. Tried with while and for loop but unable to read all the .zip files using shell script.

Can anyone have any idea on this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wrote that exact thing, see here:

https://gist.github.com/ahmed-musallam/07fbf430168d4ac57bd8c89d8be9bca5

```
#!/bin/bash
# this script will install ALL zip packages in current directory the AEM instance at 4502
for f in *.zip
do
    echo "installing: $f"
    curl -u admin:admin -F file=@"$f" -F name="$f" -F force=true -F install=true http://localhost:4502/crx/packmgr/service.jsp
    echo "done."

done
```

Comment: Thanks, Perfect Ahmed

Comment: Please mark as the correct answer. Because this is specifically what you asked for :)

Answer (score 1):

```
find . -name "*.zip" -maxdepth 1 -exec curl -u admin:admin -F file=@"{}" -F name="{}" -F force=true -F install=true http://localhost:4502/crx/packmgr/service.jsp ";"
```

Node, this will substitute `./foo.zip` instead of `foo.zip`.  If you need to strip `./`, you should probably write shell-script wrapping you `curl` command that accepts zip file name as argument and strips `./` from it before passing to `curl`.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using curl you can just copy the files over to the install folder of the AEM instance. These will get installed automatically. https://helpx.adobe.com/in/experience-manager/6-3/sites/administering/using/package-manager.html#FileSystemBasedUploadandInstallation

Comment: I knew this method but, will this use curl command in background to install?